# How to make a fullscreen iframe with opaque background?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xhtml, html

I am able to create an iframe which occupies entire screen. But I am not able to make the contents of the background hidden, In other words, I want an iframe which is opaque. I am currently trying like this:

```
   <iframe name='myifrmae' allowtransparency = 'false' background= '#FFFFFF' id = 'myiframe' src = 'main.html' 
     style='position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:400px; 
            height:100%;z-index:999' onload = 'sendParams();'' frameborder='no'>
   </iframe>
```

I am testing this on Firefox/3.5.6.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

**UPDATE:**
  I gave a BGCOLOR = "#FFFFFF" to main.html body, Now it is working fine. Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: I think the code you tried to post has mysteriously vanished.

Comment: Its back now! I forgot add code block.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
<iframe name='myiframe' id='myiframe' src='main.html' 
 style='position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%; 
        z-index:999' onload='sendParams();' frameborder='no'>
</iframe>
```

You don't need to set allowtransparency=false as this is the default. Also there were a few errors with extra quotes. Also I've corrected the spelling the name attribute.

I've changed the width to be 100% instead of the fixed width of 400 pixels to make sure that it fills the entire window.

Comment: I just tried this. It does occupy 100% but still I can see the contents of the parent HTML. I want to make this opaque, thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: Can you supply the HTML of some example HTML for the parent page and possibly the main.html page too. I can't see a single reason in the example code provided for the iframe to be transparent.

Do you have any JavaScript or CSS that might be manipulating the iframe's opacity settings?

Comment: I checked in a sample, It behaves as you have explained above. But the behavior is not same in my application. Yes, there is some rogue CSS responsible for this behavior, thanks for pointing it out. I will check this out and update the findings.

Comment: to make the iframe opaque just add the background:white, it will work ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an opaque div with an iframe in it?

Comment: Actually this iframe is under a div, but let me check how to make this opaque.

Answer (score 0):

```
allowtransparency = 'false'
```

Doesn't sound like a very good start?

Try setting 
    allowtransparency = 'true'

And then make sure that the content inside the iframe has it's opacity set to be transparent.

Comment: I dont want to allowtransparency, thats why I have made it as false. I want to load a fullscreen opaque iframe, which overlaps on the parent content.

Answer (score 0):

Full screen iFrame you would need to add margin:auto; to your styles.